Fundamental group of creative intersecting circles in the space
Are my homotopic equivalences correct?

I'm not sure about the contractions that I made, some suggestions?

They are correct, yes. What do you mean by "I'm not sure about the contractions that I made, some suggestions?"

I was insecure because my teacher contracts all of $V$ to a single point in all of the exercise and she obtained a circle less than me, but I'm not agree with her, I think it's pretty simple to do the homotopies that I made in the picture. Contracting $V$ to a single point means that a circle is contractible, but it's notoriously false.

"All of $V$" is totally unclear, you have to specify what $V$ is. If $V$ is an edge in a graph (then it is usually called $e$, not $V$) and it has distinct vertices, then indeed, contracting it to a single point is a homotopy-equivalence.

@MoisheKohan From the diagrams, their labelings and their color coding I think it's reasonably clear that $V$ is the whole purple copy of $S^1$ in each.
